# Thymeleaf multiple checkbox not showing input name

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have trouble in getting multiple checkbox value by Thymeleaf.

[Java]

```
@GetMapping("/")
public void myFunction(
///
@RequestParam(value = "selected", required = false) Integer[] selected) throws IOException {
///
}
```

[Html]

```
<div>
  <p th:each="item : ${itemList}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selected" th:field="*{itemList}" th:value="${item.id}" class="form-check-input"/>
    <label th:for="${#ids.seq('itemList')}" th:text="${item.name}" class="form-check-label"></label>
  </p>
</div>
```

[generated Html]

```
<div>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name value="1" class="form-check-input" id="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="_" value="on">
    <label for="itemList1" class="form-check-label">pjname</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <!-- /// -->
</div>
```

I want to show input name like 'selected' and '*selected' but it seems to be not shown. Parameters written like '?*=on&_=on&...'. What would be the problem?